# How to stop generating WM_CONTEXTMENU when VK_APPS key is pressed?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have handled `VK_APPS` key in `CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage()` and returned **TRUE**
(for both WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP) so that it does not go to `::TranslateMessage()` and `::DispatchMessage()`.
But the thing is, `WM_CONTEXTMENU` is still generated when I press `VK_APPS` key.
 Now I don't understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647592(v=vs.85).aspx).  In particular,

> The WM_CONTEXTMENU message is also generated when the user presses and
>   releases the VK_APPS key.

Unless you want to re-write some base code, I think your best strategy is to set a flag when VK_APPS is pressed and use that flag while handling WM_CONTEXTMENU.  You can then choose to ignore the message.

Comment: One thing i am not getting clearly is that when is WM_CONTEXTMENU message is generated by windows. Is it generated in ::TranslateMessage() or even before the message gets picked?