# Ignoring the windows menu key when focus is in an edit control

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I need to handle the Windows Menu key (`VK_APPS`) myself and not have Windows display the system popup menu containing Cancel/Cut/Copy/Paste/etc. when the focus is in an edit control.

If it's unclear which key I mean, it's this one:

[image]

Is there a way do ignore this popup menu? I tried following approach without success:

For testing this I wrote a very simple `CMyEdit` class and subclassed a standard CEdit control to `CMyEdit`.

Everything apparently works fine, `CMyEdit::PreTranslateMessage` is called, I filter out the `VK_APPS` key and the `A` key, latter just for validating the approach.

This is the `PreTranslateMessage` method which is supposed to ignore the `A` key and the Windows Menu key.

```
BOOL CMyEdit::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN || pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        if (pMsg->wParam == 'A' || pMsg->wParam == VK_APPS)
        {
            TRACE("Ignoring A and Menu key\n");
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

The `A` key is filtered out as expected (you press the `A` key and nothing happens), and so is apparently the `VK_APPS` key, but in the end the menu is displayed anyway.

This is a screenshot after typing <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>Menu Key</kbd>:

[image]

Sorry for the french menu, it's just Cancel/Cur/Copy/Paste/...

And this is corresponding debug output (WM_KEYDOWN = 100, WM_KEYUP = 101, VK_APPS = 5d, and 41 is (you've guessed it) 'A'):

```
CMyEdit.cpp(42) : atlTraceGeneral - Ignoring A and Menu key: pMsg->message = 100, pMsg->wParam = 41
CMyEdit.cpp(42) : atlTraceGeneral - Ignoring A and Menu key: pMsg->message = 101, pMsg->wParam = 41
CMyEdit.cpp(42) : atlTraceGeneral - Ignoring A and Menu key: pMsg->message = 100, pMsg->wParam = 5d
CMyEdit.cpp(42) : atlTraceGeneral - Ignoring A and Menu key: pMsg->message = 101, pMsg->wParam = 5d
```

If you need more code, let me know.

Comment: have you already look at here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317291/how-to-stop-generating-wm-contextmenu-when-vk-apps-key-is-pressed

Comment: @Federico that looks promising, looking right now.

Comment: [Other tricks with WM_GETDLGCODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031126-00/?p=41703).

Comment: @IInspectable in the actual application the edit controls are not in a dialog but in a normal window, so I'm not sure if the WM_GETDLGCODE still applies.

Comment: As long as the message loop of that window calls [`IsDialogMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isdialogmessagew) then this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I would have thought you could sub-class the edit control and block the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message also.

Comment: @JonathanPotter blocking `WM_CONTEXTMENU` does quite the opposite of what want: it prevents the popup menu from showing when you right click on the edit control, but it doesn't prevent the popup menu when you press the Menu button.